# NGINX / PHP-FPM extremely slow when accessed via https/SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, php-fpm

Starting around a week ago I began noticing terrible performance from my webapp.

My application is served on an Amazon EC2 m1.large instance.

Static files of only 4-5kb were often taking in excess of 10 seconds to receive.  This would happen intermittently but for every page load, I could expect at the very least 1 or two huge wait times for a particular resource.

From checking Firebug It was clear that the holdup was in the 'waiting' portion of the request. (DNS/connecting/sending and receiving were always fine)

Unfortunately I do not yet have the required reputation here to post an image, or I would.

To make matters worse, when a page requests lots of static resources such as Images, almost every single request seems to exhibit this problem.

Having played around with my NGINX and PHP-FPM configuration would the last week or so I have gotten no where until today when I noticed that the problem appears to only exist when the server is accessed via HTTPS.

This can be seen when using the `ab` command to test performance.

**HTTPS:**

```
ab -c 100 -n 3000 https://www.mydomain.com/

    Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,RC4-SHA,2048,128

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        13367 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   12.122 seconds
Complete requests:      3000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      41205000 bytes
HTML transferred:       40101000 bytes
Requests per second:    247.48 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       404.067 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.041 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3319.52 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       13  219  91.2    216     577
Processing:    18  178  83.5    166     562
Waiting:       10  168  80.5    156     549
Total:         60  397 124.9    386     809
```

**HTTP:**

```
 ab -c 100 -n 3000 http://www.mydomain.com/

    Server Port:            80

    Document Path:          /
    Document Length:        184 bytes

    Concurrency Level:      100
    Time taken for tests:   0.468 seconds
    Complete requests:      3000
    Failed requests:        0
    Write errors:           0
    Non-2xx responses:      3000
    Total transferred:      1431000 bytes
    HTML transferred:       552000 bytes
    Requests per second:    6404.06 [#/sec] (mean)
    Time per request:       15.615 [ms] (mean)
    Time per request:       0.156 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
    Transfer rate:          2983.14 [Kbytes/sec] received

    Connection Times (ms)
                  min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
    Connect:        3    7   2.2      8      11
    Processing:     2    8   2.4      7      18
    Waiting:        1    6   2.0      6      16
    Total:         11   15   1.4     15      28
```

I am very inexperienced when it comes to diagnosing these sorts of problem and it is quite possible that I am misreading the output of the above tool.  Regardless, despite a huge amount of searching on google I still do not know where to begin.

The relevant part of my `nginx.conf`:

```
 #SSL certs
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.key;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
 ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
 ssl_session_timeout 10m;                          
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
```

FIrstly, I would like to know if I appear to be on the right track with my assertion that it is SSL/HTTPS causing the problem.  Secondly, how are there any suggestions as to how I would go about rectifying it.

The very same config worked flawlessly until recently so I really am not sure what has happened.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
```

You'll need to remove the entry

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
```

which enables the elliptic curve Diffie-Helman Ephemeral cipher and replace it with

```
!kEDH
```

Unless you require perfect forward secrecy, this is unnecessary and is the cause of the long delays you are seeing for requests. The HIGH cipher entry should be perfectly reasonable for most applications.

*A quick edit: you can take a look at what ciphers are being negotiated using the openssl command line utility:

```
openssl s_client -host HOSTNAME -port 443
```

Replacing hostname with the ip or domain name of the server you're looking at. If you see 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA' in the 'Cipher' line before these changes, then this is most likely th problem.

Comment: You sir... are a genius.  I cannot believe that was it but genuinely has fixed the problem.  Cheers!